# How can I install Hydro and Indigo alongside on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed indigo resourcefully.PR2 is supported only for Hydro.I tried installing hydro by following official doc  (http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu)

I get following error

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-desktop-full
```

I have also run apt-get update cmd before running above command

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201670/how-can-i-install-hydro-and-indigo-alongside-on-ubuntu-14.04./) by [prrraveen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21441/prrraveen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [some](http://answers.ros.org/question/187548/can-i-install-multiple-ros-version-on-the-same-machine/) of the [other](http://answers.ros.org/question/195921/install-ros-hydro-pr2-desktop-on-ubuntu-1404-with-indigo/) answers: Hydro is not supported on Ubuntu 14.04, so you cannot `apt-get` it. See also [REP-0003](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html).

One way to get Hydro on Ubuntu Trusty is to build it [from source](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source). But I would only do this if you know what you are doing, as it is (can be) far from trivial. Another way could be to use a chroot. The ROS wiki has an example (see [Installing ROS Indigo in a chroot](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingIndigoInChroot)): you could attempt that but with Precise and Hydro. But just as for the source install, if you don't know what you are doing, it is most likely easier to get a second machine and install Precise and Hydro on it directly.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1